# Naive Bayes with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to use naive bayes in R for classification.

This is my data:

```
   Anon_Student_Id               Problem_Hierarchy Problem_Name Problem_View Number_Of_Steps Sum_Of_Steps_Duration Sum_Of_Incorrects Sum_Of_Hints CFA_ratio result
1      02ZjVTxC34 Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-1   LDEMO_WKST            1              12                   643                 0            0 1.0000000      1
2      02ZjVTxC34 Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-2       BH1T08            1              12                   199                 2            0 0.8333333      0
3      02ZjVTxC34 Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-2       BH1T15            1              11                   197                 1            0 0.9090909      0
4      02ZjVTxC34 Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-2      BH1T17B            1              11                   550                 4            0 0.8181818      0
5      02ZjVTxC34 Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-2      BH1T22C            1               8                   555                 2            0 0.8750000      0
6      02ZjVTxC34 Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-2       BH1T24            1              10                   431                 5            0 0.7000000      0
```

I need to predict the result column.
I'm doing something like what's in the iris example:

```
classifier<-naiveBayes(A[,1:9], A[,10]) <br>
predict(classifier, A[,-10])
```

but I'm getting:

```
factor(0)
Levels:
```

Why?!

Comment: try `classifier<-naiveBayes(A[,1:9], as.factor(A[,10]))`.